# Octave Ctrl-C Kills Edit Window

Tags: linux, matlab, octave, interrupt

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Octave:

```
$ octave
octave:1> _
```

I set my editor to gedit:

```
octave:1> edit editor "gedit %s"
```

I edit a function:

```
octave:2> edit someFunction
```

gedit opens someFunction.m as expected and prompt returns while gedit still has the file open:

```
octave:3> _
```

I run some other long-running function:

```
octave:3> runAllTests
```

While runAllTests is executing I press CTRL-C to interrupt it.

The observed behavior is that runAllTests is interrupted AND gedit is killed.

The expected behavior is that runAllTests is interrupted AND gedit is NOT killed.

Does anyone know how to stop CTRL-C from killing gedit in this circumstance?  Alternatively is there another way to interrupt runAllTests without killing gedit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting:

```
edit editor "gedit %s &"
```

causes octave to place the editor "in the background", so CTRL-C does not effect it and has the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
edit mode async
```

which specifies asynchronous mode of execution of the edit command

Answer (score 0):

The problem is CTRL+C is also a copy command. IT may need to be customized as in Octave GUI [Xoctave](http://www.xoctave.com). [They claim that customization is available.](http://xoctave.com/blog/how-can-i-interrupt-xoctave-when-it-gets-really-really-busy/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, putting the forked process in background with '&' is not enough when working with the command line (octave-cli).

There is a bug open on the [GNU Octave development webpage](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45654#) about this issue.

Of course it is not only an editor problem, but any new forked process is affected. For instance

```
octave> system("$TERM&")
```

creates a terminal in a new window, which would be killed by subsequent `<ctrl-c>`.

I propose a shell-based workaround. This consists in adding an additional layer of "forking in background", which would protect the final terminal (or text editor or whatever) from the signals sent to octave. In brief, I launch a terminal which launches another terminal in background, from which I kill the first terminal (so that it does not bother us).

Create an executable:

```
term-kill.sh
-----------------------------
#!/bin/sh
$TERM&
sleep 0.01
kill $1
-----------------------------
```

(note the `sleep` commands without which the second terminal does not have time to get detached from the first before the latter gets killed). Then, the command

```
octave> system("$TERM -e term-kill.sh $$&")
```

creates a single terminal which won't get killed.

To open a text editor, simply consider the executable

```
term-edit-kill.sh
------------------------
#!/bin/sh
$TERM -e $EDITOR $1&
sleep 0.01
kill $2
------------------------
```

and change the octave `edit` command through

```
octave> EDITOR('$TERM -e term-edit-kill.sh %s $$')
```

N.B.: I assumed that your system knows how to find `term-kill.sh` and `term-edit-kill.sh`, and that the variables `$TERM` and `$EDITOR` exist and suit your needs. The terminal emulator must support the `-e` option.